# HTTP Request Redirection in angular and node/express

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, express

Suppose that I have following angular `http` request which redirects to a route in the server side (node/express) to perform another `http` request to web api.

Based on the following code:

1. Would the angular `http` request will ever have `errorCallback`? If yes, under what situation?
2. What is a possible condition for the `if(error)` to produce an error in the server side http request? Is it client side http error? Any other else?
3. Should the `http` request in server side have error as true, will the app crash?

Angular http request:

```
$http({
  method: 'GET',
  url: 'webServerUrl'
}).then(function successCallback(response) {
    alert('success');
  }, function errorCallback(response) {
    alert('fail');
  });
```

Server side http request

```
var request = require('request');
exports.getSearchResults = function (req, res) {
  request({ 
        method: 'POST',
        url: 'apiUrl'
    }
  , function (error, response, body) {
      if (error) {
        res.jsonp('Unknown error. Please try again later');
      }
      else {
        res.jsonp(body);
      }
    }
  )}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Would the angular http request will ever have errorCallback? If yes, under what situation?

Yes. If the request to the server times out or fails, it will be called.

> What is a possible condition for the if(error) to produce an error in the server side http request? Is it client side http error? Any other else?

No, it will only cause an error if the call to the api fails.

> Should the http request in server side have error as true, will the app crash?

No, it shouldn't. The error object is an object, not a boolean.

By the way, you should know that it is not standard practice to issue a GET request in the client and then issue a POST request to your api. A POST request implies some sort of state change, whereas a GET should not. Either make them all GET, if the calls can be made repeatedly without any side effects, or make them all POST.